# How shoud I include css file of kendo-theme-bootstrap in plunker?

Tags: plunker, kendo-ui-angular2

In [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bNfOE0mQvWrqsvAISKeZ?p=preview), I could include *css* file of **kendo-theme-default** from [here](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/npm/node_modules//@telerik/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css).
Now I want to include *css* file of **kendo-theme-bootstrap**.

Maybe I include it from `https://unpkg.com`, but I don't know how to do this.

> For npm package authors, unpkg relieves the burden of publishing your code to a CDN in addition to the npm registry. All you need to do is include your UMD build in your npm package (not your repo, that's different!).
>
> You can do this easily using the following setup:
>    - Add the umd (or dist) directory to your .gitignore file
>    - Add the umd directory to your files array in package.json
>    - Use a build script to generate your UMD build in the umd directory when you publish
>
> That's it! Now when you npm publish you'll have a version available on unpkg as well.

This quotation is a little difficult to understand for me.
Could anyone explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, themes can be included from `unpkg` -- just as any file that is in a npm package. The correct paths for the Default and Bootstrap themes are:

```
https://unpkg.com/@telerik/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css
https://unpkg.com/@telerik/kendo-theme-bootstrap/dist/all.css
```

You may want to lock them to a specific version, otherwise you'll always get the latest version (which may contain breaking changes, if the theme gets a new major version.

Comment: How do you know these links? Where can I find them online? I want to learn the way to find them.

Comment: The theme packages are `@telerik/kendo-theme-default` and `@telerik/kendo-theme-bootstrap`. The existence of the [dist/all.css file](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/styling/#use-precompiled-themes) is documented in the styling docs. Alternatively, if you install the themes via NPM, you can browse their files (`ls -la node_modules/@telerik/kendo-theme-default/`). Once you know which file you need, you can request it via unpkg.